# Using Tryton as a python module

Tags: python, apt, tryton

I have just installed [Tryton](http://www.tryton.org) on Ubuntu 12.0.4 from the [PPA](http://code.google.com/p/tryton/wiki/InstallationOnUbuntu#Install_from_PPA).

I want to be able to interface directly with Tryton in my Python code (thereby bypassing the frontend GUI client). However, there appears to be no **useful** information on how to use Tryton, let alone how to programatically interface to Tryton and its modules.

In desperation, I decided to locate the source, so I could look at the code and familiarize myself with how it works. The problem however, is that I can't locate the source after the install (even after running `find / -type f -name 'tryton*' 2>/dev/null`) on my box.

My questions are:

1. How do I locate the source for Tryton after I have installed it using apt as outlined above?
2. Is there a resource that shows how to interface with a Tryton module? (I am already aware of [this snippet](http://code.google.com/p/tryton/wiki/HowToUseTrytondAsAModule), however, I want to know how to get the FULL API for a module).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [proteus](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/proteus/1.8.0) library, may be what you're looking for.

Also, checkout the [official docs](http://doc.tryton.org).

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
dpkg -L tryton
```

to see the contents of the package.

And, I'm not sure, but may be that

- http://doc.tryton.org/1.6/index.html

is what you are looking for?